# Recreate iOS Flipkart App product detail top view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to recreate iOS Flipkart app product detail top view as in image below
[First image when image is displayed full and detail is at bottom (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cutn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cutn.png)

[Second image as user scroll up the detail content (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXcHf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXcHf.png)

**Feature in above screens that I want to use:**

User can scroll through the product images horizontally. User can also scroll up the detail content by dragging vertically over images.

> As per my thought table view covers the whole screen with a transparent header view and a collection view stays behind the table view.

**My Approach:**

1. Add UIViewController subclass

   ```
   let viewController = ProductDetailViewController()
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
   ```
2. Add a UICollectionView below navigation bar

   ```
   var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
   let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
   layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
   layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
   layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
   let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
   collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
   collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
   return collectionView
   }()
   self.collectionView.registerClass(PDetailImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PDetailImageCellIdentifier)
   func addCollectionViewForProductImages() {
   let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
   self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: self.tableHeaderHeight)
   self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = true
   self.collectionView.dataSource = self
   self.collectionView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(self.collectionView)
   }
   ```
3. Add UITableView

   ```
   let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
   self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
   self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
   self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
   self.tableView.dataSource = self
   self.tableView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.canCancelContentTouches = false
   ```
4. Add a transparent UITableHeaderView

   ```
   let headerView = TableTransparentHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: self.tableHeaderHeight))
   headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
   ```
5. Skip touches when user drags on table header. For this, I override the hitTest method in TouchHandledTableView class.

   ```
   class TouchHandledTableView: UITableView {

       var isScrollingHorizontal: Bool?

   override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
       let hitView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
       let liesInHeaderView = self.tableHeaderView?.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
       if liesInHeaderView == true && self.isScrollingHorizontal != nil {
           if self.isScrollingHorizontal == false {
               debugPrint("hitTest returned hitView")
               return hitView
           } else {
               debugPrint("hitTest returned nil")
               return nil
           }
       } else {
           debugPrint("hitTest returned hitView")
           return hitView
       }
   }
   }
   ```
6. But this stopped table scrolling vertically. So I tried to catch weather the tableview is being dragged vertical or horizontal. To catch the scrolling direction, I added swipe gesture, touch event handler,scrollViewDidScroll but all of these are being called after hitTest method called. Once direction detected hitTest is not called in the same phase.

Comment: Y U NO USE STORYBOARD?

Comment: @JJBoursier I have no issue using storyboard. will that resolve the issue of scroll for both collection view and table view. can you please brief about it?